# Prove for a connected graph $G=(V,E)$, $\kappa(G)=1+\min_{v\in V}\kappa(G-v)$

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

$\kappa(G)$ here is the connectivity of $G$. I'm just at a loss for where to start. I thought about induction on the number of vertices since I can see that it clearly holds for trivial cases, but I can't make that work. I thought about induction on $\kappa$ but I can't make that work either. I considered starting with $K_n$ since $\kappa(K_n)=n-1$ and for any $v$, $K_n-v=K_{n-1}$, and $\kappa(K_{n-1})+1=n-1=\kappa(K_n)$, so I thought maybe I could do induction backwards by starting with the complete graph and forming whatever connected graph I want by deleting edges. Or something. But they're all dead ends I think. Can anyone think of even just a hint on how to start this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Induction is not required.
Looking what happens if you delete a vertex of a minimal cutset should give you one direction.
Find a vertex $v$ with a minimal $\kappa(G-v)$, then look at its cutset should give the other direction.